# add class in jquery is working fine but remove class is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
            $('whois').addEvent('submit', function(e) {
            new Event(e).stop();
            var log = $('log_res').empty().addClass('ajax-loading');
            this.send({
                update: log,
                autoComplete: function() {
                    log.removeClass('ajax-loading');
                }
            });
            });     
        });
```

Hi all I am new to jquery addclass is working fine ,But removeclass is not working properly . 
Any suggesstion would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code :

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
        $('whois').addEvent('submit', function(e) {
        new Event(e).stop();
        var log = $('log_res'); //Code Edit here
        log.empty().addClass('ajax-loading');
        this.send({
            update: log,
            autoComplete: function() {
                log.removeClass('ajax-loading');
            }
        });
        });     
    });
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion . I tried your code too but it doesnot work

Answer (score 0):

```
var log = $('.log_res').empty().addClass('ajax-loading');


$('.log_res').removeClass('ajax-loading');
```

i felt that `log_res as class`

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEvent('domready', function () {
        $('whois').addEvent('submit', function (e) {
            new Event(e).stop();
            var log = $('#log_res'); // or var log = $('.log_res'); if log_ref is class
            log.empty().addClass('ajax-loading');
            this.send({
                update: log,
                autoComplete: function () {
                    log.removeClass('ajax-loading');
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what is log_res

If it is id then

```
$('#log_res').empty().addClass('ajax-loading');
```

And if it is class then try this .

```
 $('.log_res').empty().addClass('ajax-loading');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not selecting the correct element.

> if log_res is class then use
>
> ```
> $(".log_res")
> ```
>
> and if it is an id then use
>
> ```
> $("#log_res")
> ```

then call the required jquery method.

hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
var log = $('log_res').empty();
log.addClass('ajax-loading');
```

Try this:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    $('whois').addEvent('submit', function(e) {
        new Event(e).stop();
        var log = $('log_res').empty();
        log.addClass('ajax-loading');
        this.send({
            update: log,
            autoComplete: function() {
                log.removeClass('ajax-loading');
            }
        });
    });     
});
```